# How to Configure Jacoco code coverage report into Java Play framwork project?

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, jacoco, jacoco-plugin

Can someone please give example of how I can set up `jacoco` report into play project? MY `Plugin.sbt` looks like below

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public") // (not entirely sure this line is necessary)
addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "jacoco4sbt" % "2.3.0")
```

and this is `val playVersion = "2.6.25"`

I tried

```
addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "jacoco4sbt" % "2.3.0")
```

in `plugin.sbt`
but when trying to run `activator jacoco:cover`
my `jacoco` folder not creating
Can some one please guide me ?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `addSbtPlugin("com.github.sbt" % "sbt-jacoco" % "3.4.0")` to your `plugins.sbt` and execute `sbt jacoco`. After that you should see a HTML report in your path `target/scala-2.13/jacoco/report/`

You can configure jacoco by you needs e.g. generating a HTML and a XML by adding

```scala
jacocoReportSettings := JacocoReportSettings().withFormats(JacocoReportFormats.XML, JacocoReportFormats.HTML)
```

in your `build.sbt`.

More information: https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-jacoco/